# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n x)}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I can't seem to solve this one. I've tried Dirichlet's test but to no avail.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want, you can actually calculate what it converges to by appealing to complex numbers.  The sum is the imaginary part of 
$$
\sum \frac{e^{nix}}{2^n} = \sum \left(\frac{e^{ix}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{2}{2-e^{ix}},
$$
so your sum converges to $\frac{2 \sin x}{5 - 4\cos x}$.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:** To show absolute convergence use that $\sin$ is bounded by 1 (I assume that you want $x$ to take real values).

Comment: right, i forgot that. sorry for being such a beginner. thank you!